# auth_token for unittest in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-rest-auth

I've been trying to test my login system using the following code

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
  
class DeckTestCase(TestCase):
 @classmethod
 def setUp(cls):
    test_user1 = User.objects.create(first_name='tester',username='test1', password='123', email='testuser@something.com')

 def test_if_logged(self):
    factory = Client()
    user = User.objects.get(username='teste1')
    request = factory.post('/login', {'username': 'test1', 'password': '123'}, format='json')
    force_authenticate(request,user=user)
    print(request)
```

But i keep getting this response, which is 401 (Unauthorized)

```
<Response status_code=401, "application/json">
```

Can someone help me? I don't know how do I send an auth_token with `test_if_logged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`.create_user(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) to create a user, this will set a *hashed* password for that user:

```
@classmethod
def setUp(cls):
    test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(
        first_name='tester',
        username='test1',
        password='123',
        email='testuser@something.com'
    )
```